# jar compile Runtime.getRuntime.exec() full directory in jar

Tags: java, jar, compilation, runtime.exec

Just for fun I'm making a little Java project file to keep on my dropbox to compile java for me without an ide easier than typing all those pesky command line arguments myself.

Right now I am just having one small problem...
First here's my code which does manage to compile class files into a jar with a manifest.

```
    public static String listFilesString(String dirLocation){
    String allPaths = ""; //pretty self explanatory returns full list of files in directory with spaces
    File f = new File(dirLocation);
    if(f.isDirectory()&&f.list().length>0){
        for(File f2 : f.listFiles()){
            if(f2.isDirectory()){
                allPaths = allPaths + listFilesString(f2.toString());
            } else {
                allPaths = allPaths + f2.toString() + " ";
            }
        }
    }
    return allPaths;
}

public static boolean compileOutputToJar(String output, String jarLocation){
    output = output.replace('\\', '/'); //replacements just for uniformity
    String binF = WorkspaceVariables.workspaceDir+output;
    String toCompile = listFilesString(binF).replace('\\', '/');
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar cvfm " + jarLocation + " " + binF + "manifest.txt " + toCompile); // this line represents the problem
        System.out.println("Compiled Workspace to Jar!");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

As is commented on the line containing Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar cvfm " + jarLocation + " " + binF + "manifest.txt " + toCompile); this is where the problem occurs. Indeed the command properly executes but I do provide the full path to the class files to be compiled into the jar.

As an example I'll use the sample project this compiles. with a directory structure of:

```
/bin/manifest.txt     <   The manifest is compiled properly
/bin/Main.class       <   Calls k.Me to get the n variable which is printed
/bin/k/Me.class       <   Defines a string 'n' equal to "hi"
```

this however is compiled into the jar as:

```
META_INF/MANIFEST.MF
Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Other/ide/javas/bin/Main.class
Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Other/ide/javas/bin/manifest.txt < Nevermind this inclusion, just a problem I've not fixed.
Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/Other/ide/javas/bin/k/Me.class
```

The problem is clear, the file cannot run while it's like this and it is plainly compiled incorrectly. I could compile it correctly by changing to the directory they're found in before execution (not found a way to do this). Or possibly changing the location during command execution (I've tried using -cp, but to no avail).

The best option seems to be the use of -C as it can move the Main.class and manifest.txt to the proper place, however it doesn't include sub-directories to Me.class and the k folder no longer exist. and adding this to the beginning of each files name by adding "-C " + f2.getParent() + " ". in the listFilesString method prevents any of the class files from compiling into the jar at all.

Thanks for any help/ contributions!

Comment: Have you considered (a) a makefile (2) Maven (3) an IDE? It's a solved problem.

Comment: The entire idea was I could make a quick project and compile it without external utilities.

Comment: And you'll end up reimplementing `make` or Maven or an IDE. It doesn't make sense to even start down this path.

Comment: This is for when I'm at school for example, where I can't run other compilers, I can write little programs in a simple text editor and compile and run it from a JDK / JRE on a USB. I've already started and I don't plan to change course. It can be done more effectively and quickly than using your suggested methods.

Comment: The original given method compiles the jar perfectly, I had forgotten to include the package names in the files to compile. But was able to achieve compilation without make, Maven or an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line was missing, a slight adjustment I've made corrected the error.

```
public static String listFilesString(String dirLocation){
    String allPaths = ""; //pretty self explanatory returns full list of files in directory with spaces
    File f = new File(dirLocation);
    if(f.isDirectory()&&f.list().length>0){
        for(File f2 : f.listFiles()){
            if(f2.isDirectory()){
                allPaths = allPaths + f2.toString() + " "; //THIS LINE WAS ADDED
                allPaths = allPaths + listFilesString(f2.toString());
            } else {
                allPaths = allPaths + f2.toString() + " ";
            }
        }
    }
    return allPaths;
}

public static boolean compileOutputToJar(String output, String jarLocation){
    output = output.replace('\\', '/'); //replacements just for uniformity
    String binF = WorkspaceVariables.workspaceDir+output;
    String toCompile = listFilesString(binF).replace('\\', '/');
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar cvfm " + jarLocation + " " + binF + "manifest.txt " + toCompile); // this line represents the problem
        System.out.println("Compiled Workspace to Jar!");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```